# Вытащить текст из буфера обмена

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как вытащить текст из буфера обмена с помощью JS или других средств?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript вам такое сделать не разрешит. Это, в конце концов, небезопасно для пользователя, иначе любая веб-страница сможет «подглядывать» за вами. То же и насчёт чистого HTML (там и выразительных средств для этого не особо много).

Mожет помочь старая версия Flash. Хотя, для свежего FlashPlayer-а запрещено чтение буфера обмена без явного действия пользователя:

> **[User-initiated action requirements in Flash Player 10](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_uia_requirements.html)**<sup>[[архив](http://web.archive.org/web/20160902204243/https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_uia_requirements.html)]</sup>**:**
>
> ... reading from the system Clipboard using the new ActionScript 3.0 API, `Clipboard.generalClipboard.getData`, can succeed only as the result of a paste event handler.

Доступ к буферу обмена [можно получить из Java-апплета](http://web.archive.org/web/20090331100706/http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=Browser_clipboard_access), но я не пробовал — возможно, пользователю придётся явно разрешить запуск этого апплета.

Comment: В общем я сделал вывод: НИКАК. СМИРИСЬ.

Comment: @igolka97: угу :(

А чего именно вы хотите достичь глобально? Какой функциональности? Расскажите, может вместе что-то придумается.

ЗЫ: Защита придумана, чтобы веб-странички не крали номера кредиток и пароли из буфера обмена. Или фотки :))

Answer (score 3):

В internet explorer для этих целей есть [clipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/ms535220(v=vs.85).aspx). В [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_the_Clipboard) есть класс, с помощью которого можно работать с буфером.

Так же стоит обратить внимание на библиотеку - [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/).

Comment: Компонента Firefox `@mozilla.org/widget/clipboardhelper` доступна лишь адд-онам. В свежем IE, надеюсь, дыру прикрыли. На ZeroClipboard распространяются те же ограничения, что и на весь Flash: доступ на чтение возможен лишь в контексте события `paste`.

Answer (score 1):

[Clipboard API and events](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html).

Как то делал реализацию подставкой скрытого textarea. БЫла задачка копировать данные с ексель в extJS таблицу, даже работало. Если найду исходник выложу проект уже старый но в архивах должен быть.

Comment: очень надеюсь)))

Answer (score 1):

```
pastEventHandler = function (e) {
    e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    // только в e.originalEvent
}
```